# Recent file viewer for Xfce?

Tags: software-recommendation, xfce, zeitgeist

Is there any other ''recent file viewer'' besides Gnome Activity Journal? Since GAJ doesn't seem to work using Xfce.

Comment: Do you want a GUI or will a script (terminal) do?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! It doesn't really matter to me, terminal is fine.

Comment: There's a nice thread here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2125130&p=12556637#post12556637 with code you can modify to your needs. Also, while it's old, here's an [Ask Ubuntu link on GAJ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24543/gnome-activity-journal-does-not-show-recently-used-files?rq=1)

Comment: @vasa1 Since your comment seems to solve the problem in the OP, please consider moving it  to a proper `answer`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this would meet your needs, but in `Xfce` you have the `Places` plugin that can show a list of recent files.

After adding it to a panel, simply <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the plug-in, access `Properties`, then enable `Show recent documents`. You may even configure the number of recent documents to include in that list. Then you can access that by <kbd>left-click</kbd> on the panel plug-in, then `Recent Documents`.